# compare date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using angularjs and moment library. I have an object `start_date` which contains several dates, once user clicks "proceed" I am comparing each date with today and throw an error in case the given date is in the past.

Here is my code:

```
$scope.checkDateTime = function(){                    
    angular.forEach($scope.orders.start_date,function(s){
        console.log('data'+s);
        if (moment(s).format('DD-MM-YYYY') < moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')) {
            swal({
                title: "Please select a valid date.",
                text: "Please select valid start date.",
                confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary add-prod-btn",
                imageUrl: 'images/vmy-sub.png'
            })
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

When I am consoling the value of `s` I am getting "27-10-2016", when I use `moment(s, 'DD-MM-YYYY')` I am getting "1477506600000".  So I think value I am getting is not string, but when I directly compare it with today's date using moment it says *"invalid date"*, I am confused. Any help please.

Comment: You can simply use [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/), in your case: `moment(s).isBefore(moment())`

Comment: The thing is start_date is not a date , its a string

Comment: How should I convert first it to date then compare?

Comment: You can [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) your string into moment object and then use moment methods. Which is the format for your input string? Maybe you can edit your question to add further details.

Comment: its giving me 1823970600000 somthing like this after momet(s, 'YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: We just need to know which is the value of `$scope.orders.start_date`, for example you can provide what `console.log('data'+s);` prints. Anyway, I suggest to edit your question to add details, instead of adding them in  the comments :)

Comment: @VincenzoC please check the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my first comment you can simply use [`isBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/) or [`isSameOrBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/).

Since your input is a string, you can [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) into moment object and then use moment methods.

Your condition will be:

```
moment(s, 'DD-MM-YYYY').isBefore(moment())
```

Comment: Can we check it for the time also? I mean user can place orders only upto 2pm? can you please have a look on this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40243375/javascript-to-check-selected-date-is-todays-date-and-time-is-2pm-using-moment-j

Comment: How do I check currentTime is greater than 2pm ? with moment?

Comment: You can check that currentTime is greater than 2pm using `moment().isAfter(moment('14:00', 'HH:mm'))`. Anyway your linked question has a good answer, in my opinion you have to edit the other question specifying that `$scope.orders.start_date` is array of strings in `DD-MM-YYYY` format and stating more clearly which time ranges are valid and which are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

There is a isAfter function available in moment you can use it.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/

Answer (score 1):

this hard work works for me try it

```
     var sDate = new Date(document.addproject.sdate.value);
     var eDate = new Date(document.addproject.edate.value);
     var today = new Date();
     var sy=sDate.getFullYear();
     var sm=sDate.getMonth();
     var sd=sDate.getDate();
     var ey=eDate.getFullYear();
     var em=eDate.getMonth();
     var ed=eDate.getDate();
    // var cymd=sDate - today;
     var cy=today.getFullYear();
     var cm=today.getMonth();
     var cd=today.getDate();
     var startdate=null;
     var enddate=null;
    // alert("some ");
     if(sy < cy){
         startdate="notgood"; 
     }
     else if(sm < cm){
             startdate="notgood"; 
         }
     else if(sd < cd){
                 startdate="notgood"; 
             }
     else{
         startdate="good"; 
     }


     if(ey < cy){
         enddate="notgood"; 
     }
     else if(em < cm){
             enddate="notgood"; 
         }
     else if(ed < cd){
                 endtdate="notgood"; 
             }
     else{
         enddate="good"; 
     }


if((document.addproject.sdate.value == "")||
            (startdate !="good" ))

        {
         alert( "Please provide project Excepted Start Date !\n" +
                "Start date must be valid  "  );
         document.addproject.sdate.focus() ;
         return false;

        }
    if((document.addproject.edate.value == "")||
            (enddate !="good"))

    {
     alert( "Please provide project Excepted End Date!\n" +
            "End date must be valid"  );
     document.addproject.edate.focus() ;
     return false;

    }
```

Comment: You can Use Moment.Js for date comparing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using simple **Javascript date methods** also. please check below.

```
$scope.checkDateTime=function(){                    
                angular.forEach($scope.orders.start_date,function(s){
                    console.log('data'+s);
                    s = new Date(s);
                    var today = new Date();
                    if (s.getTime() < today.getTime()) { // Here "getTime()" converts the date to milliseconds where you can compare in terms of milliseconds. this worked well for me.
                        swal({
                              title: "Please select a valid date.",
                              text: "Please select valid start date.",
                              confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary add-prod-btn",
                              imageUrl: 'images/vmy-sub.png'
                            })
                        return false;
                    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)